# Crash and xmx memory issue when importing a Symfony2 project from a remote server with PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, sftp, remote-server, jetbrains-ide, phpstorm-2017.1

I have a PHP Symfony2 project on a remote server. And I've to import it with PhpStorm (latest) to continue to work efficiently.

To do so, I've followed [this official JetBrains process](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/create-new-project-add-remote-server.html) . It has worked great until the importation became very long and crashed with this dialog box:

[image]

I tried several time to modify the `-Xmx` memory from 720MB to 5048MB, but my issue remains (becoming very long with the display of the dialog box above).

I don't know what to do. Have you already experienced the same issue?

Comment: You can import/create project by 3 ways: 1) creating new project and download all files you need 2) create new project and perform clean framework install and then download project files that you need 3) if you have some version control for your project - associate with it and then do operations from 2nd approach

Comment: I want to import project directly from the remote server because I want to be able sync it regularly afterwards with my server. How could I do it with your approach ?

Comment: To sync files you have to set up deployment in the 'remote host' tab. Also you have to specify mappings and document root in those settings

Comment: OK I gonna try to do it your way and see if it'll work.

Comment: Do what @AlexSlipknot said -- the best way. And put `-Xmx` back to "normal" values